# Save Django Website State across all browsers the app is accessed at

Tags: python, html, css, django, postgresql

I have created a Django webiste which fetches data on a realtime basis through view and renders to the Html Template, I am already running serveral ajax queries to refresh my specific views to render and display data every second, but now i have a bigger problem which is to maintain the same state of the template accross all the browsers the Django server is accessed at. For example If user 'A' logs in  and do certain operations on the webiste which changes the states of tables in my pstgres, and after an hour user 'B' logs in with same credentials he should be able to see the same operations running but right only the raw template is visible to user 'B'. I have created the middleware using postgres.

I am not getting the solution to this since a long time now. I tries using ajax to call every view once but i don't think this solution is a long term because as more views get added more and more ajax calls will slow down the system.

Comment: Please provide some of your code

Comment: So essentially what you want is a way to automatically sync data across multiple clients. Websockets (Django Channels) offers a real-time way to send events, but you still have to somehow manage events on the server. Building something like that is beyond the format of a simple question/answer.